# Is there a way to connect directly to Salesforce's REST API directly from JS?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cross-domain

I get a [cross origin error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) when I do an AJAX call, and am wondering if there´s a way to solve that.
Thanks!

Comment: You may need to provide more information, platform you are using, is it visual force, another website, etc. Also any code snippets that are relevant would assist in an answer being given. Otherwise your question may be closed for being unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) is a good way to deal with the limitations around cross-origin requests.

> [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/) is a W3C recommendation that enables Web browsers to request
>   resources from origins other than their own (cross-origin requests).
>   For example, using CORS, a JavaScript script at
>   https://www.example.com could request a resource from
>   https://www.salesforce.com.

With Winter '15 Salesforce added CORS support to the Chatter REST API.  You can read more about it here: [Winter '15 Release Notes: CORS](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter15/release-notes/rn_chatter_api_general.htm#cors)

James Ward has also created a proxy that adds the CORS headers to Salesforce's REST APIs here: [Salesforce CORS Proxy](https://github.com/jamesward/sf-cors-proxy) and he has written a blog post about it here: [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) for Salesforce.com](http://www.jamesward.com/2014/06/23/cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors-for-salesforce-com)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use REST API directly. You need to have some proxy page which will set headers. Normally we use "ForceTK" library to route all request to proxy page.

Here are some articles by pat -

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2014/12/ringing-changes-force-com-javascript-rest-toolkit.html

https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2013/06/calling-the-force-com-rest-api-from-visualforce-pages-revisited.html

Example of using ForceTk using Nodejs

https://github.com/JitendraZaa/SOQLBuilder

https://github.com/JitendraZaa/ToolingAPI30Min-AceEditor