# Javascript SOAP API external access

Tags: javascript, soap-api, soap

I am trying to call our Salesforce SOAP API from an external server using JavaScript, but I am getting an error because the URL it is using is from my localhost server. I am getting this error:

> POST http://localhost:8888/services/Soap/u/33.0 404 (Not Found)
>   connection.js:594

I am using the **connection.js** on my login.salesforce.com server and passing my credentials by `sforce.connection.login(username, password)`;

Comment: have you downloaded javascript files from Salesforce server and uploaded them outside of salesforce?

Comment: no. which files were you thinkin?

Comment: can you provide more details as to where are you trying to access Salesforce API from. How are you using connection.js

Comment: I am trying to access it from a local webserver. I moved around the login call with an init call before it.
sforce.connection.init("null", "https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0");
Now I get a different error:
https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/33.0. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8888' is therefore not allowed access.

Comment: you should probably find your answer at http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/60344/is-there-a-way-to-connect-directly-to-salesforces-rest-api-directly-from-js